# Independence of Shocks in ARCH(1): A Doubt from Hayashi’s Book

Tags: time-series, econometrics, stochastic-processes, garch

I am reading Hayashi's Econometrics book, and on pages 104 and 105 he defines the ARCH(1) model for a time series $g_i$ as:

\begin{aligned}
g_i &= \sqrt{h_i} \varepsilon_i, \\
h_i &= \zeta + \alpha g_{i-1}^2, \\
\varepsilon_i &\sim iid(0,1).
\end{aligned}

He then says that $g_i$ depends on $g_1$ and the shocks $(\varepsilon_2, \varepsilon_3, ..., \varepsilon_{i-1})$. Due to this, he concludes that $\varepsilon_i$ is independent of $(g_1, g_2, ..., g_{i-1})$.

I don't understand this argument. How does the dependence of $g_i$ on $g_1$ and the shocks imply the independence of $\varepsilon_i$ from the previous values of $g_i$?

Can someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since $\varepsilon_i\sim iid(0,1)$, $\varepsilon_i$ is also independent of any function of $(\varepsilon_1,\dots,\varepsilon_{i-1})$.
2. $g_1$ is a constant (I suppose) and every $g_j$ for $j>1$ is a particular function of $(\varepsilon_1,\dots,\varepsilon_{j-1})$.
3. The set $(g_1,\dots,g_{i-1})$ is thus a particular function of $(\varepsilon_1,\dots,\varepsilon_{i-1})$.
4. Thus, $\varepsilon_i$ is independent of $(g_1,\dots,g_{i-1})$.